# In Matlab how do I automatically plot a set of vectors with means and error bars?

Tags: matlab

E.g.

Vector1, vector2, vector3, vector4...

I want to be able to automatically plot these vectors with means and error bars attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`errorbar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html), for example

```
errorbar(Vector1,Err)
```

plots Vector1 and draws an error bar at each element of Vector1. The error bar is a distance of Err(i) above and below the curve so that each bar is symmetric and 2*E(i) long.

Another example:

```
load count.dat;
y = mean(count,2);
e = std(count,1,2);
errorbar(y,e,'xr')
```

[image]

Note, all this was taken from Matlab's documentation, so next time try to read the documentation.